# Generating and saving images in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image, uiscrollview

I want to be able to generate an image from a set of data.  After the image is generated, I want to save it to the photo album and display it inside a scroll view.  How do I tell the application to create an image?  After the image is created, how do I display it inside of a scroll view?  Simultaneously, how do I save that image to the photo album?

Without going into too much detail here is what my app does:

It takes in a set of data that the user inputs (mainly integer data), then converts this into an image using Core Graphics (I can generate an image and display it to the view controller by  generating a new class for the view [of subclass UIView] part of the view controller).  Now I want to be able to save that image for further use (I want to be able to save an unlimited number of images so NSUserDefaults is not what I want).  A PNG file would be ideal, but I know that a conversion has to be made in order to do that.

Things I am thinking of trying:

UIImage has a lot of creators, but I don't know which one I want to use.
Should I create a new class to generate the image?
Should I generate the image in another view controller and save it there and access it in the view controller that I want to display it?  Should I skip Core Graphics all together and just use OpenGL ES (I have experience with OpenGL, just not on the iPhone)?

Comment: I have tried the following and have gotten the image to save: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions //to generate the image and modelImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); //to save the image.  I have gotten it to save to the photo album, but I cannot get it to save the text that I put on with the following code: UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24.0];
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    [proteinName drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(15.0f, 125.0f) withFont:font];
    [proteinLength drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(length-100.0f, 125.0f) withFont:font]; //wont show in the photo albm

Comment: Try ALAsset library to save and retrieve photo-library Images.Save your UIImage using ALAsset Library, it will return an Asset URL to retrieve it back after done the save process.. see details here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't give much detail about what you are doing, so it's difficult to advise in other than general terms:

1. How are you generating your image?  If it is UIImage-based it is trivial to save the image -- use [UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html).  That documentation also illustrates PNG and JPEG representation functions.
2. If you don't already have a UIImage (i.e., you are just rendering into a graphics context), there are different ways to handle what you want.  Review the Core Graphics docs on [CGBitmapContextCreateImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html) and the UIKit docs on [UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html).

UPDATE:

With regard to the text, are you invoking the draw methods prior to the `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` call?

I usually use a Core Graphics variation on your method, but the logic is similar:

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(...);
// ... do some other drawing...
NSString* foo = @"Foo";
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
[foo drawInRect:bounds withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
```

Comment: I am generating the image using the drawRect method inside the UIView class.  I am currently reading up in the developer library on Core Graphics and think I may have stumbled onto the same thing as you are saying.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Thanks, @jstevenco. This was a huge help to getting it to work.  I now have an issue where I cannot see the text that I put on the image using the drawAtPoint method.  I can see it in my scrollview, but not in the image that is saved to the photo album.  Am I not adding it to the context? Or is it just not saving properly?